# Mysql Query for >= and <= is not showing the correct result

Tags: mysql

I have a table which contains column named 'extension' and its varchar type.Now for querying  >= and <= is not showing accurate result.Is is showing only the last <= digit result..

Here is my query.

```
SELECT *,date(calldate) as date,time(calldate) as time FROM data_table
where date(calldate) between '2010-10-01' and '2013-10-01'
and cast(extension as signed) >=00 And cast(extension as signed) >=11111
ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 0 , 50
```

On executing given query result is coming for only extension for '11111' not for 00 and 11111.

Any help will be appreciated..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Maybe it's because you have `>=11111` instead of `<=11111`.

Comment: if `extenstion` has to be greater than or equal to `11111` it will never also be `0`

Comment: Why did you add a `00`? It seems you think it is a string :/

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- Is calldate a DATE?  or a DATETIME?  What datatype is `extension`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cast(extension as signed) <=11111
```